# Vittime e morti

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

Ho sempre pensato che la definizione di vittima fosse "chi subisce le conseguenze" (spiacevoli). Per questo motivo, mi ha sempre infastidito il linguaggio giornalistico quando usa la parola vittime intendendo morti, perché secondo me se, per esempio, in un incidente ci sono due feriti e due morti, le vittime sono quattro. Attribuisco questo uso del termine a uno scopo eufemistico, anche se ritengo che cozzi col sensazionalismo che i giornalisti sono a inclini a usare, specie nei loro titoli.

Ho fatto quindi una ricerca sulla definizione di vittima. I dizionari più classici danno come primo significato quello di "vittima sacrificale" e, solo come estensione, "chi muore o subisce grave danno" (https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/vittima.shtml e http://treccani.it/vocabolario/vittima). Già qui sono rimasto un po' perplesso: pur essendo d'accordo (mi fido) che in origine il termine designasse l'oggetto di un sacrificio, direi che oggigiorno il primo significato non sia più quello,
e quindi citerei quel significato solo dopo quello comune.

Passando al senso figurato, il Sabatini-Coletti recita "chi muore o subisce grave danno", e questo è il significato che pensavo io, specialmente nel contesto di un incidente o un'epidemia. Ma il Treccani dice diversamente: "chi perisce", escludendo perciò chi subisce danni meno gravi. Quindi, l'uso giornalistico si rifà al Treccani. Ma qui: https://www.wordreference.com/iten/vittima la traduzione del lemma "vittima (ferito o morto)" ritorna a dare torto al Treccani.

Questo altro sito https://it.bab.la/dizionario/italiano-inglese/vittima cita una serie di frasi prese qua e là, e si trovano "L'Irlanda è la prima vittima", "cittadini che sono rimasti vittima di un reato", "se sarà adottato io sarò la prima vittima (on. Bossi)", "Io stesso ne sono rimasto vittima in passato" (morto che parla?), "L’8 per cento dei lavoratori nell’UE dichiara di essere stato vittima del...".

Queste ultime frasi usano tutte il significato più esteso, che però secondo me è il principale;
questo uso è documentato dal Coletti nella terza accezione, e dal Treccani al punto b), ma trovo che in quest'ultimo caso il significato è spiegato malissimo, ponendo l'accento su inganno prepotenza sopraffazione prepotenza persecuzione e oppressione. Anche Hoepli definisce il termine in un modo molto simile al Treccani, con grande precisione che non include l'uso che se ne fa sovente.

Ancora non contento, ho consultato dizionari inglesi, ragionando sul fatto che l'importazione del
termine in inglese, forse più pura, potrebbe fare più luce. Il dizionario di Cambridge dice
"someone or something that has been hurt, damaged, or killed...", e corrisponde pienamente al
mio pensiero (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/victim), e anche Oxford cita "a person who has been attacked, injured or killed as the result of a crime, a disease, an accident, etc.".

La domanda finale è questa: "è corretto l'uso della parola *vittima* per indicare solo i morti?"

Comment: Riporto qui, come dato in più, che cosa dice lo Zingarelli (dopo il significato di base riferito ai sacrifici e prima di usi più figurati): “chi perde la vita o subisce gravi danni personali o patrimoniali, in seguito a calamità, sventure, disastri, incidenti e sim.”.

Comment: “...citerei quel significato solo dopo quello comune”: La norma più o meno tacita in lessicografia è di andare dal significato letterale, originario, specifico a quelli via via più traslati, figurati, successivi. Ovviamente nulla vieta, e forse esiste anche, di immaginare un dizionario incentrato più sull'uso contemporaneo.

Comment: @DaG cominciare dall'accezione più comune è un'idea mia, nutrita da malintesi che ho visto proprio su questo sito. Vorrei più informazioni sulla regola tacita che citi: se non è tacita si può trovare qualche informazione in più?

Comment: Se il senso originario di "vittima" è quello di persona o animale ucciso come sacrificio offerto a una divinità, mi sembra naturale che questo significato venga prima esteso a quello di essere vivente che viene ucciso e che poi man mano si venga ampliando a altri  sensi traslati di "sacrificio". Quindi, non vedo perché non si potrebbe usare "vittima (da)" col significato di "qualcuno che è ucciso (da)".

Comment: Giusto, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, non è per niente tacita. Cito dall'introduzione dello Zingarelli 2020 (e probabilmente ci sono spiegazioni analoghe in altri dizionari):

Comment: “L'ordinamento delle accezioni all'interno della voce segue di solito un criterio che vuol essere logico e storico al tempo stesso: precedono cioè le definizioni dei significati propri od originariamente più in uso e seguono quelle dei significati figurati, estensivi, specifici, ecc. In tal modo, leggendo tutta la voce, ci si può rendere conto della logicità storica che regola i passaggi semantici dall'uno all'altro significato come passaggi dall'implicito all'esplicito, dall'indifferenziato al differenziato.”

Comment: @DaG: Sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/8) si legge: «Le accezioni sono state ordinate, dove ciò non fosse troppo in contrasto con il loro uso, secondo un criterio cronologico, a partire da quella più antica. [...] In questi casi, il criterio della successione cronologica delle accezioni è stato abbandonato a favore di un ordinamento che privilegia ai primi posti le accezioni avvertite come più importanti e frequenti nell’uso».

Comment: Ma anche sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/vittima), che segue questo criterio per ordinare le accezioni, quella che appare per prima è: «animale o essere umano consacrato o immolato a una divinità». Quindi, a giudicare dalla spiegazione su questo criterio, questa accezione non è considerata come "troppo in contrasto" con l'uso che si fa oggigiorno di "vittima".

Comment: [Sinonimi e Contrari del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vivo_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) dà "vittima" come contrario di "vivo".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Non ho ben capito la tua domanda. Stai cercando di ricostruire i passi di una catena polisemica?

Comment: @nico: credevo che fosse chiara! Nessuna catena, no... vorrei solo capire: secondo me "vittima" non vuol dire morto ma chi subisce; alcuni dizionari lo confermano ("chi muore o subisce gravi danni") ma il Treccani no e, pare, che i giornalisti prediligano la definizione del Treccani: sovente dicono "vittime" invece di "morti".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Ora capisco meglio ciò che intendevi. A mio avviso, il termine "vittima" si è specializzato per indicare morti e non solo lesi in un contesto come quello che descrivi. Mi riesce difficile accettare una frase del tipo "nell'incidente ci sono stati quattro vittime, di cui due sono morte e due se la sono cavata"...